# Did I do this $\chi^2$ test for discrete uniform distribution correctly?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test

I had to test if a certain lottery based on choosing numbers is fair – whether the distribution of winning numbers is uniform. In this lottery you pick six numbers from 1 to 49. Six numbers are then drawn as the winning numbers.

I have data about how many times each number was drawn as one of the winning numbers during last ~10000 draws, for example – 1 was drawn 200 times, 2 was drawn 207 times and so on..

So I want to check if the probability distribution of those numbers is:

$
\begin{align*}
f(n) = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{49}, \ n = 1, 2, \dots 49 \\ 0, \ n \neq 1, 2, ...49 \end{cases}
\end{align*}
$
(Null hypothesis: it is like this)

So I calculated: $\chi^2 = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{49} \frac{(a_k - A_k)^2}{A_k} \approx 41.2,$

where $a_k$ is a measured number of draws of $k$ and $A_k$ is the theoretical number of draws of $k$ ($A_k$ equals always $\frac{10000}{49}$).

For significance level $\alpha = 0.05$ the critical value of chi-squared test is $\chi^2_{\text{crit.}} \approx 65.1$. We have: $\chi^2 < \chi^2_{\text{crit.}}$, so we have no reason to reject the null hypothesis.

Is it correct?

Comment: it is just the opposite. In your case the p-value is less than 0.05. So you reject the null hypothesis at the 0.05 level.

Comment: @MichaelChernick What do you think the p-value is in this instance?

Comment: Sorry. I didn't see that the critical value was 65.1. Of course since the value of the test statistic is below the critical value the p-value is higher than 0.05 & you would not be able to reject the null hypothesis. The degrees of freedom is large which eplains why the p-value is so high.

Comment: Facts for reference: In R, `qchisq(c(.5,.95), 48)` returns 47.33500 for the median and 65.17077 for the 5% critical value. The expected value is df = 48, the mode is df - 2 = 46; as per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution). Also, code `1 - pchisq(41.2, 48)` returns the P-value
0.7456482.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The test statistic is not merely below the critical value; it is actually below what you expect it to be if $H_0$ were true - and even below the median and indeed, even the mode (it's close to the 25th percentile of the null distribution of the chi-squared statistic). Your conclusion is correct.

However, note that the critical value is closer to 65.2 - and if you're rounding, many people would expect you to round up rather than down (or more generally, toward the values of the statistic most consistent with the alternative).